# Unable to catch the 'auth' event in Hub.listen while calling Auth.federatedSignIn

Tags: single-page-application, aws-amplify, solid

I am using SolidJS and building a SPA (no server rendering). For authentication, I use the `@aws-amplify/core` and `@aws-amplify/auth` packages. At the application root I call the `Hub.listen` function:

```js
Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload }) => console.log(payload));
```

In the `SignUp` component I call `Auth.federatedSignIn`:

```js
const SignUp = () => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {
      Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google });
    }}>
      Sign up
    </button>
  );
}
```

I have configured the Amplify as such:

```js
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        region: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_REGION,
        userPoolId: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_POOL_ID,
        userPoolWebClientId: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
        oauth: {
            domain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_URL,
            responseType: 'code',
            redirectSignIn: location.origin + '/account/external',
            redirectSignOut: location.origin + '/my',
        },
    },
});
```

When I click on the button I am redirected to the `import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_URL` (simply outside of my app), choose an account, and then return back to the `/account/external` page. At that time I expect a consoled **payload** object in Web tools, but there is nothing. I get it when I call `Auth.signOut()`, so I assume that I configured Amplify correctly and `Hub` is subscribed to the `auth` channel.

My thoughts were that Hub cannot catch any events because after returning the application basically renders again in a new context and Hub simply isn't able to catch anything (events aren't sent from AWS?). I tried to declare the `urlOpener` function under the `oauth` property in the config and Google's sign page opened in a new tab, but even then I couldn't get any events in the preserved old page (from which I called `Auth.federatedSignIn`).

Questions:

1. How should I organize the code to get the **signIn** and **signUp** events?
2. Can I pass some data into the `Auth.federatedSignIn` to get it back in the `Hub.listen`, so I will be able to join the **CognitoUser** with the data that existed at the time of starting Sign in/Sign up (I want to add a new login type to existed user)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example regarding the first question. Just check that your listener is set before you call the Auth.federatedSignIn() method.

```
   export default class SignInService {
      constructor(private landingFacade: LandingFacade) {
        this.setupAuthListeners(); // Should be called at the top level.
      }
    
      private setupAuthListeners() {
        Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
          switch (event) {
            case 'signIn':
              this.landingFacade.signInSuccess();
              break;
            case 'signIn_failure':
              console.log('Sign in failure', data);
              break;
            case 'configured':
              console.log('the Auth module is configured', data);
          }
        });
      }
    
      public async signIn(): Promise<void> {
        await Auth.federatedSignIn();
      }
    }
```

For the second one: I'll use a local state and set/query the object you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I called `Hub.listen` before even `Amplify.configure` and got `parsingCallbackUrl` and `configured` events at the start. 
Unfortunately, a local state isn't preserved after returning back from the provider's oAuth page.

Comment: Maybe, if you'll describe with more details the second issue, I can give you some hints.

Comment: Didn't get if the first issue is fixed. If not, it really depends where you subscribe to the listener. In my case, I'm using Angular and it should be called from somewhere within Angular context. In the above example, is a service class provided within Angular. If I just call it from the place where the Amplify.configure is called, it will not get triggered.

Comment: You helped me with the first issue. Sorry, if I didn't express it clearly. I subscribe to the `Hub` right before calling the `Amplify.configure` and everything works. To resolve the second issue I am using `sessionStorage` because it can preserve the data after the "social authentication round-trip". I need a unique storage per each opened tab, so that is the second reason why I chose the `sessionStorage`. Perhaps, you meant `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` by "local state". If so, I am doubly grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Move hub.listen method in file where you called Amplify.configure(awsconfig)
2. When calling federated sign in, send custom state like this:

```
import {CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider} from "@aws-amplify/auth/lib/types"

Auth.federatedSignIn({provider:CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google, customState:'whatever'})
```

Then hub listen event customOAuthState will return text 'whatever'